# ¿Hay algún equivalente al "III" del "John Doe, III" inglés para nombres en castellano?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, nombres-propios, sufijos

En [Name Suffixes “Sr” (Senior) and “Jr” (Junior) in Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5208/1674) se preguntó por los sufijos usados en castellano para el Senior y Junior inglés. La respuesta aceptada indica *padre* e *hijo* como mejores opciones, cosa que me parece bastante coherente.

En los nombres estadounidenses también es común encontrar nombres del tipo Mr. John Doe, III. Hay un montón (por ejemplo, en FilmAffinity encontré [238 películas con algún actor con *III* en su nombre](http://www.filmaffinity.com/es/advsearch.php?stext=iii&stype%5B%5D=cast): Walter Hendrix III, Tirso Cruz III, Otávio III...).

¿Qué opción os parece mejor para su equivalente en castellano? Siguiendo con lo indicado en la respuesta referenciada, *nieto* parecería lo más adecuado. Sin embargo, no recuerdo haber encontrado nunca en España esta terminación.

¿Existe algún consenso al respecto?

Comment: Acaso eso no significa tercero? En español hemos usado esos sufijos por siempre para la realeza y los papas que son los que mas tienden a "reciclar" los nombres p.ej. Juan Pablo II, Enrique VIII, Juan XXIII etc por lo que me imagino que si un nieto se llama igual que su padre y su abuelo podríamos también usar III (tercero) sin problemas.

Comment: @DGaleano sí, pero el tema es que en la terminología de reyes no es necesario que sean hijos. Felipe VI (el actual rey de España) no es hijo de Felipe V (que murió hace mucho). Lo de _senior_ y _junior_ se utiliza en Estados Unidos (y no sé si en algún otro lugar) para designar padres e hijos con el mismo nombre: George Bush senior, George Bush junior. Cuando viene un tercero, se le añade ese _III_.

Comment: Sr, Jr, III no usamos en Reino Unido.

Comment: @mdewey that is interesting. So when father and son have the same name  what do you use to differentiate them? Do you use "father" and "son" as in Spanish?

Comment: @fedorqui El Tirso Cruz III de tu ejemplo es Filipino (ex-colonia Española) y nació en 1952.  El Octávio III lo encontré en IMDB como Otávio Terceiro (no hay información pero parece de origen brasilero).  Por ahora solo hay una respuesta que sugiere que se use el segundo apellido pero creo que los latinos que se han encontrado antes con esta situación también han decidido usar III

Comment: @DGaleano I do not know but I suspect that since we do not have a common solution parents avoid the situation, We did have prime ministers called Pitt the elder and Pitt the younger but that is not a current usage as far as I know.

Comment: @mdewey I see Wikipedia has some comments on [Suffix (name)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_(name)): _In the United States the most common name suffixes are senior and junior, which are written with a capital first letter ("Jr." and "Sr.") with or without an interceding comma. In Britain these are more rare, but when they are used the abbreviations are "Jnr" and "Snr", respectively_. However, your comment makes me wonder how much rarer this is.

Comment: @mdewey I added a question about it in [english.se]! [How widespread is the usage of Senior, Junior, III in British English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/366453/37429).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creo que la razón por la que no hay una equivalencia es la diferente forma de tratar los nombres en ambas culturas.

En el mundo anglosajón si tres generaciones de hombres tienen el mismo nombre es necesario establecer una distinción:

```
(Grandpa) John Doe
(Father)  John Doe
(Son)     John Doe
```

Sin embargo en las mujeres no es necesario, ya que pierden su apellido al casarse:

```
(Grandma)  Jane Doe   --> Jane Brown
(Mother)   Jane Brown --> Jane Smith
(Daughter) Jane Smith --> Jane Jordan
```

En el mundo hispano no es necesario añadir nada para distinguir a las personas porque **es muy improbable (aunque no imposible) que se produzca una situación en la que tanto el nombre como los 2 apellidos coincidan entre diferentes generaciones (*).**

Tanto en hombres:

```
(Abuelo) Juan Pérez López
(Padre)  Juan Pérez Aguilar
(Hijo)   Juan Pérez Martín
```

Como en mujeres:

```
(Abuela) María Pérez López 
(Madre)  María Aguilar Pérez
(Hija)   María Martín Aguilar
```

(*) Las reglas son:

- Cada persona tiene dos apellidos: el primero del padre y el segundo de la madre.
- Las mujeres mantienen su apellido original durante toda la vida.

Answer (score 1):

La distinción generacional siempre es legítima cuando hay ambigüedad, la cual puede depender de casos y contextos.

Caso 1- varias generaciones llevan el mismo nombre. Se puede utilizar numeral cuando son 2 o más homónimos. Jr y Sr se pueden utilizar solo cuando 2 o más estan vivos.

Caso 2- el nombre y el primer apellido son los mismos, el segundo apellido es distinto: Se desambigúa con el segundo apellido, salvo en caso que en el contexto donde se deba diferenciar, se utilice por cualquier razon solo nombre y apellido: Juan Bross Ortiz y Juan Bross Valladares pertenecen a un club deportivo. Por costumbre, en dicho club, la gente usa el nombre de pila y primer apellido. Tendríamos Juan Bross Sr y Juan Bross Jr o Juan Bross I y Juan Bross II. Este caso lo comparte el derecho nobiliario ya que la costumbre es solo utilizar el nombre de pila.

El uso del numeral se permite incluso cuando hay brincos generacionales y relaciones de segundo grado, rigiendose por el orden de nacimiento.

Saludos,

Mario Brondo III