# ¿Cuál es la traducción de "Seniority" en español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, informática

Hace días un amigo que desarrolla software tuvo una entrevista en la que querían medir su nivel de *seniority*. Para un poco más de contexto sobre la clasificación junior-senior, la [respuesta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14914/whats-the-difference-between-entry-level-jr-sr-developers/14972#14972) a esta pregunta en softwareengineering.stackexchange está muy interesante.

Siempre había pensado que en español no había equivalente para junior y senior, pero a través de [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21099/17686) vi que existen los equivalentes y que júnior y sénior también aplicarían para estas categorías para las que estoy hablando. Por ejemplo, para sénior:

> [**sénior**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XZlFiwY)
> Del lat. *senior*, comp. de senex '*viejo, anciano*'.
>
> 4. adj. Superior en categoría y experiencia a quienes desempeñan la misma profesión o cargo. Analista sénior.

Con esto, me queda la duda de cuál es la mejor traducción de *seniority* en español. Algunas cosas que he encontrado:

- Google translater propone "antigüedad". No me convence esta traducción. Es muy genérica y ser antíguo no implica necesariamente tener experiencia superior.
- [Pons](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/englisch-spanisch/seniority)  propone además "veteranía". La acepción 2 de [veterano,na](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bi1RtCG)  en el DLE: " *adj. Que ha desempeñado durante mucho tiempo una profesión o un oficio, o tiene experiencia en una actividad*". Esta suena posible, pero no sé si refleja la mísma idea que sénior: "Superior en categoría y experiencia..."
- Yo me imaginé el término "senioridad", pero no existe en el DLE.

¿Existe una traducción oficial o adecuada para "seniority"?

Comment: Que no exista en el DLE no significa que no puedas crear una palabra derivada con el sufijo adecuado, podría valer *senioridad* o *senioría*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que no hay traducción oficial para ese término y se suele usar el anglicismo. El problema es que el término representa no solo cuánto has estado en un cierto puesto (antigüedad o veteranía) sino lo que sabes o puedes hacer debido al tiempo que has ejercido esas funciones (experiencia o conocimiento). Una persona joven puede tener un puesto de sénior debido a sus excelentes habilidades o experiencia, pese a ser joven.

En cualquier caso,  y por proponer o comentar algunas posibilidades o curiosidades, una posibilidad sería `preparación`:

> [preparación](http://dle.rae.es/?id=U3ig61U)
>
> 2. f. Conocimientos que alguien tiene de cierta materia.

Así, por ejemplo "[¿Cómo diseñar tu CV según tu seniority?](https://www.clarin.com/entremujeres/trabajo/en-busqueda/disenar-CV-seniority_0_rJNI4RYv7l.html)" podría traducirse como "¿Cómo diseñar tu CV según tu preparación?".

Aunque a mi me cuadra mejor `maestría':

> [maestría](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ns4bORB)
>
> 1. f. Arte y destreza en enseñar o ejecutar algo.

en algunos sitios tiene el significado de curso de posgrado, por lo que podría entenderse que se hace referencia a la titulación, no a la experiencia en un área.

De igual manera `pericia` es

> [pericia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Sc2spqb)
>
> 1. f. Sabiduría, práctica, experiencia y habilidad en una ciencia o arte.

Aunque ninguna de estas posibilidades recogen por completo el sentido del anglicismo `seniority`.

Otra posibilidad podría ser `solera`, y aunque ninguna de [las acepciones de "solera" de acuerdo al DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YHHXz2R%7CYHICGnN) expresa "madurez o veteranía" la expresión "tener solera" se usa para expresar que se tiene mayor antigüedad.

> Se dice que "tiene solera" todo aquello que por haber pasado tiempo posee antigüedad o se ha convertido en tradición.
>
> La frase proviene del ámbito de la enología. Y se dice del vino añejo o del que más tiempo ha pasado en la bodega.
>
> fuente: [Tener solera](http://www.1de3.es/2013/06/24/tener-solera/)

Comment: Me gusta especialmente _maestría_ para España, pues efectivamente en Hispanoamérica (no sé si por todo) se asocia con una titulación de postgrado. De hecho, para el DPD [maestría es sinónimo de máster](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=maestr%EDa).